# Single sign on within clustered Weblogic 12c environment

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on

Environment:

- Weblogic 12c Admin Server with multiple clustered Managed Servers
- Multiple applications deployed to those clusters

So what I am looking for is a way to allow people to bounce from one application to another within the cluster, or even the admin server, without having to re-authenticate for each application.  I am hoping for a very simple solution that doesn't involve buying a product or anything like that... I am hoping I am just missing some configuration within Weblogic that would allow those credentials to be shared across the cluster, or range of clusters (admin server).

Answer (score 0):

One (easy) way to achieve SSO is to have multiple applications sharing the same session. However this setting is not turned ON by default. You can overrides this default setting by set the sharing-enabled attribute in the session descriptor to true in the weblogic-application.xml deployment descriptor, something like below

```
<session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>memory</persistent-store-type>
    <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
    <cookie-max-age-secs>9800</cookie-max-age-secs> <!-- various -->
    <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
</session-descriptor>
```

Comment: I am reading that this solution may not work with EARs?  Or it may not work across clusters managed by the same admin server.  Can you confirm?

Comment: too late to see this hope you found the answer by now. the solution works with EARs files as long as in the same domains and deployed across on the cluster level.

Comment: @KexinZ it is not working for me. I have localhost:8080/app1 (app1 is ear having war and hence I added session descriptors to both weblogic.xml of war and weblogic-application.xml for ear) and want to access its session in localhost:8080/app2. app1 has authentication part so I want to access session of app1 in app2. Note app1 and app2 both are different ear